# How to set MS Teams to use Spacebar to unmute?

Tags: windows-11, microsoft-teams

MS Teams can use <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to unmute.

I want to use just <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>, like Zoom does.

Is there a way to change that keyboard shortcut?

Edit: I have searched the MS Teams Forums extensively. All that turns up is how to use Control+Spacebar which is a lot harder to do on-the-fly.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: There is no way to do that.

Comment: @harrymc - [Keyboard Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/keyboard-manager) should make this possible

Comment: @Ramhound: It's not that simple - this should be for Teams only, and it works as long as it's pressed and stops when unpressed. AutoHotKey could do that, but keeping the pressed/unpressed specification is not that simple. Keyboard Manager would do that for all of Windows, and I don't know how well.

Comment: @ramhound in manager will let me do app specific replacements but then I wouldn't be able to to type a plain SPACE, eg in the Chat.  However that's a good Power Toy to know about. Thx!